# How to make layout false in Laravel If request is ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have trying to load a page using simple get request

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("li").click(function(e){

         e.preventDefault();

         var href = $("a",this).attr('href');

         $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: href,

            success: function (response) {

               $('#main-content').html(response);
            }
         })
      });
   });
</script>
```

In response I am getting content with full layout. But Here I am trying to get only content without layout. In controller I have written code like below

```
public function index()
{
    if ($request->ajax()) 
    {
        $this->layout = null; //but same result 
    }
    $tags = Tag::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    return view('admin.tags.index')->with('tags',$tags);
}
```

But I am getting same result with layout, how can I make layout false ? Or can change layout in controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the renderSections

```
return view('admin.tags.index')->renderSections()['content'];
```

https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/render-view-without-layout

Comment: I actually don't need json data or response. I need full page content or element without layout. In page there has p tag, h1 tag, some buttons, table etc.

Comment: Can you emit the layout in the View Page i.e. @layout('layoutname')

Comment: I have make layout false in controller/action , Do you know how to change default layout in method or in action ?

Comment: Or you can use the renderSections - 
**return view('admin.tags.index')->renderSections()[$tags];**

Comment: renderSections  can be a solution. Can you give an example how to rend only content section ?

Comment: Yes it's worked !! Can you update your ans ? I will accept.

Comment: Sure, I am updating the answer, please mark as solved. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are still returning a `view`. Why not do:
`return response()->json(["data"=>"some data"]);`
after your Ajax check? This will return a JSON response to your frontend.

Comment: I am rendering full page, so ajax response will not work. Here I am trying loading page using ajax.

Comment: Ah, so you want to return the html content of a blade view without the full html and body blocks? Your blade template is probably extending from a base layout. Maybe you can do something like this: @if(condition)
   @extends("base")
@endif

Comment: @MaartenVeerman I tried it but it does not work. What it do is show the view first and then append the layout code making it out of flow.